# Android SearchView automatically closed on navigate after update

Tags: android

I have written a simple Anrdoid App. To get an instant search that filters a list while typing in the searchview, I used searchView.setOnQueryTextListener to handle onQueryTextChange. Also I wanted that opening the search should always navigate to the according search list view fragment so I had added searchView.setOnSearchClickListener with onClick doing

```
navController.navigateUp();
navController.navigate(R.id.action_nav_to_song_list);
```

All was working fine but now after I updated my app to the latest state with the android studio wizard the search is broken. When I click on the magnifier icon to open the search, it shows and immediately disappears what renders the search unusable and the app being broken.
During a long and nasty debugging session I figured out that now android seems to automatically close the search when I `navigate`.
How can I fix this?
I already spent many hours trying to figure out if I am already at the search list view and then suppress the navigation. The android `NavController` API is really ugly so already doing this was hard to figure out and what I did seems more like a hack.
However, when I am in a different dialog and click on the search, it still gets closed automatically and I have to click it again to open it. That is better than noting but I want to stop the searchView getting automatically closed. How do I archive this?